# Oracle Select where NCLOB is Like some string

Tags: oracle, select, nclob

I have an Oracle table, and in this table I have a column of type `NCLOB`. I would like to perform a `SELECT LIKE` on it like so:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
T_WEB_TASK_IT
WHERE DBMS_LOB.substr( T_WEB_TASK_IT.ISSUE_DESCRIPTION , 32000, 1)
LIKE '%Turning on the%'
```

But it isn't working, I get an error saying:

> String buffer too small

But I don't understand how can that be, cause I know for a fact that there aren't that many characters in that column for that particular record!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DBMS_LOB.INSTR` function to search for strings in the lob. Like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   T_WEB_TASK_IT
WHERE  DBMS_LOB.INSTR( T_WEB_TASK_IT.ISSUE_DESCRIPTION , 'Turning on the') > 0
```

Comment: This does not work, I get an invalid relational operator error :/

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add `> 0`. dbms_lob.instr is a function, so you must compare the result.

Comment: It should work. If you don't get results, then maybe there are no rows with that sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from DBMS_LOB.INSTR, you could also use Regular Expressions:

```
SELECT *
FROM T_WEB_TASK_IT
WHERE regexp_like(issue_description, 'Turning on the')
```